# scala api for delta lake optimize command

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

The [databricks docs](https://databricks.com/blog/2018/07/31/processing-petabytes-of-data-in-seconds-with-databricks-delta.html) say that you can change zordering of a delta table by doing:

```
spark.read.table(connRandom)
     .write.format("delta").saveAsTable(connZorder)

sql(s"OPTIMIZE $connZorder ZORDER BY (src_ip, src_port, dst_ip, dst_port)")
```

The problem with this is the switching between the scala and SQL api which is gross. What I want to be able to do is:

```
spark.read.table(connRandom)
     .write.format("delta").saveAsTable(connZorder)
     .optimize.zorderBy("src_ip", "src_port", "dst_ip", "dst_port")
```

but I cant find any documentation that says that this is possible.

Is there a scala api for delta lake optimization commands? If so, how do I replicate the aforementioned logic in scala?

Comment: This is now available in Delta OSS and DBR 11+ -https://docs.delta.io/2.0.0/optimizations-oss.html#language-python (python and scala)