# LOAD DATA is not supported for datasource tables

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am new to ADB and trying to load data into a table in databricks using a parquet file and i am giving the following command :

```
load data local inpath '/FileStore/tables/Subsidiary__1_-2.parquet' into table Subsidiary
```

But it is throwing the error as follows :

> Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: LOAD DATA is not supported
> for datasource tables: `default`.`subsidiary`;

Can anyone explain why this is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: see the answer by Jacek, but it works only in specific situations

There is no such command in Spark SQL as `load data`.  The closest one is [INSERT INTO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65098666/scala-api-for-delta-lake-optimize-command) that allows to insert data into table from other table.

But if you really want to access data in the given file, then you can use [CREATE TABLE](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-table-datasource.html) instead.  Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Subsidiary
USING PARQUET
LOCATION '/FileStore/tables/Subsidiary__1_-2.parquet'
```

Comment: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-dml-load.html

Comment: @Jacek Laskowski - you are right, I so rarely use it, so forgot about it... anyway, create table will accomplish the same

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-dml-load.html) of Databricks about `LOAD DATA` (highlighting's mine):

> Loads the data into a **Hive SerDe table** from the user specified directory or file.

According to the exception message (highlighting's mine) you use a Spark SQL table (*datasource table*):

> AnalysisException: LOAD DATA is not supported for **datasource tables**: `default`.`subsidiary`;

The easiest is to `DESCRIBE EXTENDED` it and verify yourself that the Provider is not `Hive` but something else (e.g. `parquet`).

### Demo

```
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.0.1
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.12.10 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 11.0.9)
```

```
scala> spark.range(5).write.saveAsTable("demo")
```

```
scala> sql("DESCRIBE EXTENDED demo").show(truncate = false)
20/12/29 21:57:35 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database global_temp, returning NoSuchObjectException
+----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
|col_name                    |data_type                                                     |comment|
+----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
|id                          |bigint                                                        |null   |
|                            |                                                              |       |
|# Detailed Table Information|                                                              |       |
|Database                    |default                                                       |       |
|Table                       |demo                                                          |       |
|Owner                       |jacek                                                         |       |
|Created Time                |Tue Dec 29 21:57:09 CET 2020                                  |       |
|Last Access                 |UNKNOWN                                                       |       |
|Created By                  |Spark 3.0.1                                                   |       |
|Type                        |MANAGED                                                       |       |
|Provider                    |parquet                                                       |       |
|Statistics                  |2582 bytes                                                    |       |
|Location                    |file:/Users/jacek/dev/oss/spark/spark-warehouse/demo          |       |
|Serde Library               |org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe   |       |
|InputFormat                 |org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat |       |
|OutputFormat                |org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat|       |
+----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
```

```
scala> sql("load data local inpath 'NOTICE' into table demo")
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: LOAD DATA is not supported for datasource tables: `default`.`demo`;
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.LoadDataCommand.run(tables.scala:317)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:79)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$logicalPlan$1(Dataset.scala:229)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3618)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:100)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:160)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:87)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:764)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3616)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:229)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.$anonfun$ofRows$2(Dataset.scala:100)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:764)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:97)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.$anonfun$sql$1(SparkSession.scala:607)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:764)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:602)
  ... 47 elided
```